# how to store pieces in gomoku

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

am currently learning MFC and decided to make the game Gomoku. this is the code I have so far.

```
**mainframe.h** 

class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{

public:
CMainFrame();
protected: 
DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMainFrame)


public:


public:


public:



public:
virtual ~CMainFrame();
#ifdef _DEBUG
virtual void AssertValid() const;
virtual void Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const;
#endif


protected:
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
void DrawBoard(CDC* pDC);
int m_nNextChar;
int board[15][15];
static const int EMPTY = 0, WHITE = 1, BLACK = 2;

public:
afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
afx_msg void OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
afx_msg void OnPaint();
};


**mainframe.cpp**

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "01.win32tomfc.h"

#include "MainFrm.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// CMainFrame

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)

ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
ON_WM_RBUTTONDOWN()
ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

int diameter = 23;
int size = 40;
int xCod;
int yCod;
int xCodx;
int yCody;
// CMainFrame ¹¹Ôì/Îö¹¹

CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
m_nNextChar = BLACK;

Create(NULL, _T("Generic Sample Application"));
CRect rect(0, 0, 700, 700);
CalcWindowRect(&rect);
SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(),
    SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOREDRAW);
}

CMainFrame::~CMainFrame()
{
}



// CMainFrame Õï¶Ï

#ifdef _DEBUG
void CMainFrame::AssertValid() const
{
CFrameWnd::AssertValid();
}

void CMainFrame::Dump(CDumpContext& dc) const
{
CFrameWnd::Dump(dc);
}

#endif //_DEBUG


// CMainFrame ÏûÏ¢´¦Àí³ÌÐò



void CMainFrame::DrawBoard(CDC * pDC)
{
CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
CPen* pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&pen);

for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
    pDC->MoveTo(40 * i, 40);
    pDC->LineTo(40 * i, 640);

    pDC->MoveTo(40, 40 * i);
    pDC->LineTo(640, 40 * i);
}

pDC->SelectObject(pOldPen);
}


void CMainFrame::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
CClientDC dc(this);

CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
CPen* pOldPen = dc.SelectObject(&pen);
dc.SelectStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);

xCod = (point.x + (size / 2)) / size;
xCod = (xCod * size) - diameter / 2;
yCod = (point.y + (size / 2)) / size;
yCod = (yCod * size) - diameter / 2;
xCodx = xCod + diameter;
yCody = yCod + diameter;

if (m_nNextChar != BLACK )
    return;
else {

    if (xCod > 20 && yCod <= 640 && xCodx < 655 && yCody > 40) {
        dc.Ellipse(xCod, yCod, xCodx, yCody);
    }
}

m_nNextChar = WHITE;


CFrameWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


void CMainFrame::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
CClientDC dc(this);

CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
CPen* pOldPen = dc.SelectObject(&pen);
dc.SelectStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);

xCod = (point.x + (size / 2)) / size;
xCod = (xCod * size) - diameter / 2;
yCod = (point.y + (size / 2)) / size;
yCod = (yCod * size) - diameter / 2;
xCodx = xCod + diameter;
yCody = yCod + diameter;


if (m_nNextChar != WHITE)
    return;

else {

    if (xCod > 20 && yCod <= 640 && xCodx < 655 && yCody > 40) {
            dc.Ellipse(xCod, yCod, xCodx, yCody);
        }
}

m_nNextChar = BLACK;

CFrameWnd::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}


void CMainFrame::OnPaint()
{
CPaintDC dc(this); 
DrawBoard(&dc);

}
```

the code I have draws a 15 X 15 grid in the function DrawBoard() and draws the black and white pieces in the OnLButtonDown and OnRButtonDown respectively. thing is when I run the program and click to draw the black piece and then the white piece, the white piece can be drawn over the black piece and vice versa. so I thought to create a two-dimensional array board[15][15] to store a piece when its drawn so that a different piece cannot be drawn over a current piece would be best(am I on the right track here). I tried but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. am not very good at programming and realize this might be easy but some help would really be appreciated. please explain how I would go about it the right way.

this is what I tried.

```
void CMainFrame::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
 CClientDC dc(this);

 CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
 CPen* pOldPen = dc.SelectObject(&pen);
 dc.SelectStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);

xCod = (point.x + (size / 2)) / size;
xCod = (xCod * size) - diameter / 2;
yCod = (point.y + (size / 2)) / size;
yCod = (yCod * size) - diameter / 2;
xCodx = xCod + diameter;
yCody = yCod + diameter;

if ((m_nNextChar != BLACK) && (board[xCod][yCod] = WHITE) )
    return;
else {

    if (xCod > 20 && yCod <= 640 && xCodx < 655 && yCody > 40) {
        dc.Ellipse(xCod, yCod, xCodx, yCody);
        board[xCod][yCod] = BLACK;
    }
}

void CMainFrame::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
CClientDC dc(this);

CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
CPen* pOldPen = dc.SelectObject(&pen);
dc.SelectStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);

xCod = (point.x + (size / 2)) / size;
xCod = (xCod * size) - diameter / 2;
yCod = (point.y + (size / 2)) / size;
yCod = (yCod * size) - diameter / 2;
xCodx = xCod + diameter;
yCody = yCod + diameter;


if (m_nNextChar != WHITE && (board[xCod][yCod] = BLACK))
    return;
else {

    if (xCod > 20 && yCod <= 640 && xCodx < 655 && yCody > 40) {
            dc.Ellipse(xCod, yCod, xCodx, yCody);
            board[xCod][yCod] = WHITE;
        }
}

m_nNextChar = BLACK;

CFrameWnd::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do all the drawings in `OnPaint`. Don't draw in other functions such as `OnLButtonDown`. Instead, get the necessary information from `OnLButtonDown` and call `Invalidate`, this will repaint the window.

Here is an example. For simplicity, I created a structure `info` and a 2-dimensional array `data`. `data` stores all the information for each cell, that is the rectangle and color. You have to initialize `data` once, and paint based on the information in `data`

```
#include <vector>

class CMainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
    ...
    struct info
    {
        CRect rect;
        int color;
    };
    std::vector<std::vector<info>> data;
};

CMainFrame::CMainFrame()
{
    ...
    data.resize(15);
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
        data[i].resize(15);

    int xoffset = 20;
    int yoffset = 20;
    for(int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 15; col++)
        {
            data[row][col].rect.SetRect(0, 0, size + 1, size + 1);
            data[row][col].rect.MoveToXY(xoffset + row * size, yoffset + col * size);
        }
    }
}

void CMainFrame::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CFrameWnd::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    for(int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 15; col++)
        {
            if(data[row][col].color)
                break;

            if(data[row][col].rect.PtInRect(point))
            {
                data[row][col].color = WHITE;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Invalidate(FALSE);
}

void CMainFrame::OnRButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    CFrameWnd::OnRButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    for(int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 15; col++)
        {
            if(data[row][col].color)
                break;

            if(data[row][col].rect.PtInRect(point))
            {
                data[row][col].color = BLACK;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Invalidate(FALSE);
}

void CMainFrame::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CPen pen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    dc.SelectObject(&pen);
    CBrush white, black;
    white.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    black.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));

    for(int row = 0; row < 15; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 15; col++)
        {
            dc.Rectangle(data[row][col].rect);

            if(data[row][col].color)
            {
                CBrush *oldbrush;
                if(data[row][col].color == WHITE)
                    oldbrush = dc.SelectObject(&white);
                else
                    oldbrush = dc.SelectObject(&black);
                dc.Ellipse(data[row][col].rect);
                dc.SelectObject(oldbrush);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for the help. is there a specific reason we shouldn't do any drawing in other functions?

Comment: I should have clarified. It's okay to paint in `DrawBoard(CDC* pDC)` or any other function, as long as painting is in response to `WM_PAINT` message (MFC catches `WM_PAINT` and passes it to `OnPaint`). The way you had set it up earlier, if you resized the window, that would have forced a paint message, and all the ellipses would be erased.